# How to know which row has invoked a trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, database, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger that will be invoked whenever a row is created in a specific table,
Let's say there's a table "A" and there's another table "B", what i want to do is i want to insert a record in Table "B" whenever a record is inserted in table "A" but with primary key of the record that was inserted in table "A".

What solution i came across is that i can take the primary key of last inserted record of table "A" but it may create problem if more than two users are trying to insert at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of your auto increment primary key within an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER using `NEW` :

```
CREATE 
TRIGGER `insert_on_table_a`
AFTER INSERT ON `table_A`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_b (table_a_ID) VALUES (NEW.ID);
    END IF;
END;
```

In this example, your auto increment column of table_a is ID, and you get it's value using `NEW.ID`

Comment: So NEW.ID will give me last id that was created on insertion in table A?
What if some other row is also created in table A within that time?

Comment: mysql like many RDBMS handles this for you using a lock system that will prevent any insert while another (and its triggers) are not completed. This takes milliseconds and is transparent for the user